# Graphical representation of a complex region

Tags: complex-numbers

Let us consider the principal argument of a complex number $z$, that we denote by $\arg(z)$. What is the graphical representation of the region

$$
0 \le \arg((z-1)^2)\le \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the condition $ 0 \le w \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ is equivalent to requiring that the real and imaginary parts are positive. Now let $z=x+iy$ so 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(z-1)^2=(x-1+iy)^2=(x-1)^2-y^2+2iy(x-1).
\end{eqnarray*}
We require $(x-1)^2-y^2 \geq 0$ and $y(x-1) \geq 0$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $\arg(z^n)=n\arg(z)$ to turn the inequality into $$0\leq\arg(z-1)\leq\frac{\pi}{4}.$$
Now, if you can work out the region $$0\leq\arg(z)\leq\frac{\pi}{4}$$ you should be able to finish the question (Hint: think about the relation between the graphs of $y=f(x)$ and $y=f(x+1)$ and try to see if a version of it works in $\Bbb{C}$).